# Auto recurring payment for subscriptions plan in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-ipn

Here, I'm want to using auto recurring payment in paypal for my subscription plan. I have found some solutions but not working in IPN recurring payment.
First time payment is working but not getting recurring payment auto deduction.

i'm using html code for payment in paypal gateway.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

    <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="alice@mystore.com">

    <!-- Specify a Subscribe button. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
    <!-- Identify the subscription. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Alice's Weekly Digest">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="DIG Weekly">

    <!-- Set the terms of the regular subscription. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="5.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">

    <!-- Set recurring payments until canceled. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">

    <!-- Display the payment button. -->
    <input type="image" name="submit"
    src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif"
    alt="Subscribe">
    <img alt="" width="1" height="1"
    src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
</form>
```

Comment: which html code you are using?

Comment: i was read official document guide of paypal here is the link - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/html-example-subscribe/

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: why my question is going in minus rating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For auto recurring payment you have to use ipn also. Add below code in your HTML form before submit button.

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="User_id">
<!-- specify urls -->
<!-- paypal_cancel_url -->
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://localhost/xxxxx/paypal/cancel">
<!-- paypal success return url -->
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost/xxxxx/paypal/success">
<!-- paypal ipn return url for auto recurring payment -->
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://localhost/xxxxx/paypal/ipn">
```

- I'm only showing recurring payment guide as you said first time payment is working. Add below code in PayPal controller.

```
function ipn(){


   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST") die ("No Post Variables");
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

    // Read the post from PayPal
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    /* i'm using sandbox for demo change it with live */
    $paypalURL = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';


    // Now Post all of that back to PayPal's server using curl, and validate everything with PayPal
    // We will use CURL instead of PHP for this for a more universally operable script (fsockopen has issues on some environments)
    //$url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"; //USE SANDBOX ACCOUNT TO TEST WITH
    //$url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"; //LIVE ACCOUNT

    $curl_result=$curl_err='';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$paypalURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Content-Length: " . strlen($req)));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , 0);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    $curl_result = @curl_exec($ch);
    $curl_err = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $req = str_replace("&", "\n", $req);  // Make it a nice list in case we want to email it to ourselves for reporting

    // Check that the result verifies with PayPal
    if (strpos($curl_result, "VERIFIED") !== false) {
        $req .= "\n\nPaypal Verified OK";
    } else {
        $req .= "\n\nData NOT verified from Paypal!";
        //mail("email@gmail.com", "IPN interaction not verified", "$req", "From: email@gmail.com" );
        exit();
    }


    if (array_key_exists("txn_id", $_POST)) {

        /* all response for future use conver it into json format */
        $payment_rawData = json_encode($_POST);

        $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
        $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
        $amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
        $currency_code = $_POST['mc_currency'];
        $custom = $_POST['custom'];
        $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];

        //Insert tansaction data into the database
        $payment_info = array('payment_userId'=>$custom,'payment_planId'=>$item_number,'payment_txnId'=>$txn_id,'payment_amount'=>$amount,'payment_currency'=>$currency_code,'payment_status'=> $payment_status,'payment_rawData'=>$payment_rawData,'createdDate'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),'updatedDate'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

        $this->paypal_model->insertTransaction($payment_info);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Let me check code.